# Slow FullText Search because of Hash Match

Tags: sql, full-text-search, sql-server-2008-express

I have wrote a FullText Search Query with CONTAINS predicate. when i execute it, it takes long time to return the result. i have examine the execution plan and it shows a Hash Match (Right Semi Join) with a cost of 84%. i'm using SQL Server Express 2008

Is there a way to avoid Hash Match ?

```
  SELECT    [DocumentId], [PageId]
  FROM      [dbo].[DocumentFulltextData]
  WHERE     CONTAINS(InnerText,'"and"') OR CONTAINS(InnerText,'"*and*"')
```

**Execution Plan**
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/43952220/ExecutionPlan.png

**Hash Match Details**
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/43952220/HashMatchDetail.png

Comment: Have you indexed the InnerText column?

Comment: Yes. i have create a fulltext index for InnerText column.